# Can't use § as a keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't use `cmd+§` as a keyboard shortcut anymore after the recent update of January 2023 (version 1.75)
When I try to assign that keyboard shortcut, it shows `cmd+[IntlBackslash]`, and when saved, it shows
[image]

Did anyone else have such a problem? How t resolve it?
I am using the default English Input source ABC on keyboard settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a regression, introduced in 1.75. Based on this report (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173325), the team is planning to release the fix in Insiders today/tomorrow and 1.75.1 Stable soon.

They provided a potential workaround which consists of editing the scan code based user bindings to use key code, until the fix is available (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173325#issue-1570100995).

Hope this helps